# Return all subsequences of a String

Tags: string, matlab

I'm trying to write pseudo-code and an algorithm in Matlab, to return all the subsequences of a string.

So the string `X = {ABCD}` will return `XSubSequence = {A, B, C, D, AB, AC, AD, BC, BD, CD, ABC, ABD, BCD, ABCD}`, order does not matter of course.

```
clear
x = 'ABC';
XSize = length(x);
count = 1;
i=1;

for i=1:XSize
    ZSubSequence{count} = x(i);
    count = count + 1;
    for j=i+1:XSize
        temp = strcat(x(i),x(j));
        ZSubSequence{count} = temp;
        count = count + 1;
        for k=i+2:XSize
            if j ~= k
                temp = strcat(x(i), x(j), x(k));
                ZSubSequence{count} = temp;
                count = count + 1;
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Is there any way to make this more dynamic, so I can add `X` of any size and it will be able to deal with it?

Comment: If you are trying… what have you tried?

Comment: We can help with rectifying your approach or suggesting improvements over that; plain question like this, looks directly from your assignment.

Comment: @Simon and @ kiddorails Yes, I have been trying, each time I have been tripping up over the layout of the loops. Also a little embarrassed, as the code is not doing any of what I wish, I was drinking so I could blame that, just out of practice. Some code above added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it. It only has one loop (no nesting), so it shoud be pretty fast.

```
x = 'ABCD';
n = length(x);
subseq = x.';
for ii = 2:n
  subseq = strvcat(subseq, x(nchoosek(1:n,ii)));
end
subseq_deblanked = deblank(mat2cell(subseq, ones(size(subseq,1),1), n));
```

The results are:

- `subseq`: char matrix where each row contains a subsequence padded with blank spaces.
- `subseq_deblanked`: cell array of strings with the blank spaces removed, as you specified

Comment: Nice, I'm going to read into it a little more, I'm trying to figure  out if I can feed in x as being different sizes, as opposed to the fixed 4.

But I can see how that would be extremely fast!

Comment: @Levz Yes, you can use an arbitrary size. But there was a mistake: the last `4` should be `n`. I've corrected my answer. Please try now

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider a completely different approach. 
This this is a binary representation of decimal numbers from 1 to 2^length(x)-1. Meaning for your example 1100=12 will be AB and 0011=3 will be CD, 1000 will be A and 1111=2^4-1=15 will be ABCD and so on. 
You might want to create this sequence and then translate it into the input output you have.

Example code:

```
x = 'ABCD';
XSize = length(x);

seq=dec2bin([1:2^XSize-1]);
```

And now all have left is translate it back to letters

```
for i=1:1:2^XSize-1
 for j=1:1:XSize
   if seq(i,j)=='1'
      seq(i,j)=x(j);
   else
      seq(i,j)='_';
   end
 end
end
```

Obviously the '_' should be removed and the output formatted the way you want them to be.

Comment: I had added, that this will be of assistance in another section, but it will not be of help for my current requirements, but thank you again!